# Can Google Drive redirect with POST parameters, the GET parameters are causing a 403

Tags: php, google-drive-api

When Google Drive redirects a file open event to my PHP handler callback page, my server is responding with a 403 error. I have figured out that it is because it cannot handle the JSON within the GET parameters, so is there any way we can clean up this redirect and tell Google Drive to send them via POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible right now - sorry. Why are you having trouble reading the JSON in the GET parameters? have you seen the [PHP example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php) for how to do it?